# Unable to receive notification using firebase, Application crashes

Tags: java, android

I am able to get the firebase token successfully, But application crashes with following exception when I receive any notification from server.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException: uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.ContextImpl
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java: 2675)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java: 175)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1384)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 146)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5602)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 1283)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 1099)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.ContextImpl
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java: 2657)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java: 175)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1384)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 146)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5602)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 1283)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 1099)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My `app.gradle` has following dependencies :

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
```

My `project.gradle` has following dependencies :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

FirebaseMessageInstance  class:

```
   public class FirebaseMessageInstance extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d("REFRESH_TOKEN",refreshedToken);
    }

}
```

MessagingService class:

```
    public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: will you please post your firebase java code here for helping you..

Comment: Can you post some code?. The answer of your problem is here `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.ContextImpl`
You are trying to cast incompatible class types

Comment: I got the solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @PunitVajpeyi you should share the solution here, it'll be useful for others who visit this question.

Comment: @Punit I have this same problem, could you please post your solution?

Comment: @cvanbeek We were wrapping the object with the CalligraphyContextWrapper in the class extending the application class, which was causing to crash the application. So we just commented that for the time being.

Comment: This might be a possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392706/fcm-unable-to-instantiate-receiver-com-google-firebase-iid-firebaseinstanceidr/52253216#52253216)