# FCM : Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver:

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo

App is crashing while receiving push notification in Oreo(8.0) only .

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.ContextWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.ContextImpl
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1677)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
```

Comment: It'll be nigh impossible to answer your question if you don't show where on your code that this crash is happening.

Comment: i get only above exception there is no error/exception in code. Since the crash is in oreo 8 version only when receiving notification i am doubting the below line. String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same issue when using Calligraphy library. Even it was crashing the first time after installing when Firebase requests a token for the first time. Not only receiving push notifications.

My error was I was overriding attachBaseContext method in my Application class to return a ContextWrapper object, but was only needed in Activities.

So to resume my solution is to remove attachBaseContext in Application class and move it or just place it into activities.

Answer (score 6):

This might help; add these to your proguard if you are using it!

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what solved the issue for me when trying to build with R8 enabled.

Comment: That fixed it for me too!

Comment: Suggested edit: Add new file "proguard.cfg" to the Xamarin.Android project (root), paste the configuration proposed above, set Build Action of "proguard.cfg" to "ProguardConfiguration".

Answer (score 4):

i just removed `attachBaseContext` from `Application` class:

```
    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
    val lang: String = newBase.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        .getString(KEY_LANG, ENGLISH) ?: ENGLISH
    super.attachBaseContext(ApplicationContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, lang))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue 'Unable to instantiate receiver' I added above mentioned rows to the proguard.cfg. I compiled with d8 Dex Compiler and r8 for Code shrinker. However the problem was not solved.
So I switched Code shrinker to proguard. However, ProGuard is no longer supported anymore in combination with d8 Dex Compiler. So I switched the Dex compiler to dx. And guess what?

The issuue was solved: no crash of the app anymore.